# How to find radius of a circle drawn inside a triangle, if we know the base and the distance from point to the circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, tangent-line

> How to find radius of a circle drawn inside a triangle, if we know the base and the distance from point to the circle

[image]

Here we can see the problem described in the title, we know only the distances a=3 and b=18, how would we go about solving for the circle radius?

Even though it may not look like it on the picture, the circle is tangent to all 3 sides of the triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $c$ is the length of one of the legs of the isosceles triangle, $h$ its height and $r$ the radius of the incircle, then we get the following equations:
$$
\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2 + h^2 = c^2 \\
\frac{b + 2c}{2}\cdot r = \frac{bh}{2} \\
a+2r = h
$$
The first equation is just the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) applied to one half of the triangle, the second one uses two different methods of calculating the area of the triangle, and the third one is obvious.

Note: the area of a triangle can be expressed as half of the product of the perimeter of the triangle and the radius of the incircle, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle).

Let us write those equations differently:
$$
h^2 = \left(c+\frac{b}{2}\right)\left(c-\frac{b}{2}\right) \\
\left(c+\frac{b}{2}\right)\left(2r\right) = bh \\
2r = h-a
$$
Putting the $2r$ from the last equation into the second one and solve the second one for $h$:
$$
h=\frac{c+\frac{b}{2}}{c-\frac{b}{2}} \cdot a
$$
which means
$$
\left(\frac{c+\frac{b}{2}}{c-\frac{b}{2}} \cdot a\right)^2
= \left(c+\frac{b}{2}\right)\left(c-\frac{b}{2}\right)
$$
or
$$
\left(c-\frac{b}{2}\right)^3-\left(c+\frac{b}{2}\right)a^2 = 0
$$
Now we substitute $x=c-\frac{b}{2}$ and we get
$$
x^3 - a^2x -a^2b = 0
$$
In general, there is no "nice" solution to this cubic equation, but with the given numbers $a=3$ and $b=18,$ we get $x=6$. (Use, for example, the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and check all integer factors of $a^2b$.) From here, it is easy to obtain

$c=x+\frac{b}{2} = 6+9 = 15,$ $h=\sqrt{c^2-\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2} = \sqrt{15^2-9^2} = 12$ and $r=\frac12(h-a) = 4.5.$